# Meteor 1.0 - Custom Authentication Rules

Tags: meteor, neo4j, meteor-accounts

I've a meteor app which uses Neo4j as a database with [neo4jreactivity](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/ostrio-Neo4jreactivity) driver. Since I'm not using Mongo, `Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function(err) {...})` doesn't work. My question is:

How do I define custom authentication rule to login to the app?

kind of like:

```
customLogin(email, password, function() {...});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Accounts.registerLoginHandler` method to accomplish this. This function allows developers to add custom authentication methods.  Check out https://meteorhacks.com/extending-meteor-accounts.html for a great article with more details.

You likely want to continue to use `loginWithPassword`, and register a `loginHandler` similar to the one in Meteor's accounts-password package (see
[Meteor's implementation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js#L140) ), with the call to `Meteor.users.findOne(selector)` replaced with a database lookup in Neo4j.

If you want to use a custom login method, your code might look something like the code from [here](https://meteorhacks.com/extending-meteor-accounts.html) (modified for the purposes of this question).  Note that this code is not complete, nor is it a secure means of authenticating:

```js
// client-side

// This function can be called to log in your users, and will
// trigger the following
Meteor.loginWithNeo4j = function(email, password, callback) {
    //create a login request with the email and password passed in
  var loginRequest = {email: email, password: password};
  
  //send the login request
  Accounts.callLoginMethod({
    methodArguments: [loginRequest],
    userCallback: callback
  }); 
};  

// server-side

Accounts.registerLoginHandler(function(loginRequest) {
  // loginRequest is a JS object that will have properties
  // "email" and "password as passed in the client  code
  
  // -- here you can write code to fetch the user's ID from the database
 // take a look at https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js#L61
 // to see how meteor handles password checking
  
  return {
    userId: userId
  }
});
```

The accounts package in general has a lot of dependencies on MongoDB, but you should be able to piece together various methods from the package to get auth to work.

Comment: I'm doing something like this but I would like to return more information from my custom login handler... say, I have the full name of the user stored in the external service, and I would like to return it for display on the client... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To fetch user's object use:

```
Meteor.neo4j.query('MATCH (a:Player {_id: "kE3ypH4Um"}) RETURN a').get().a[0]
/* or by email */
Meteor.neo4j.query('MATCH (a:Player {email: "name@domain.com"}) RETURN a').get().a[0]
```

Also see [updated driver API](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/ostrio-neo4jdriver)